# Php code not interpreted in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello friends developers,

I need an explanation regarding the interpretation of my php code in jquery.

this is my code in jquery using $_post

```
 var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post('/public/create_account', { data: $this.serialize()}, function (data) {

            if (data.reponse == "ok") {
                $('#signup').modal('hide');
                alert('it's ok');
            }
            else {

            $("#errors").html("<\?php  if (errors) : \?>"+
              '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in">'+
              '<span style="font-size:16px;line-height:20px;font-weight: 700;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>' +
              ' Oops ! errors .</span>'+ 
              ' <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>'+
              ' <ul style="list-style:none;"><br>'+
              " <\?php  foreach (errors as error) : \?>"+
              ' <li>'+
              '  <span class="help-block" style="color:#a94442;"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;"<\?php  echo error ; \?>"</span>'+
              '   </li>'+
              "   <\?php  endforeach \?>"+
              ' </ul></div>'+
              "    <\?php  endif \?>")
            }
```

this is my code in php

```
  $validation = $this->validator->validate($request, [
        'civilité' =>                 v::notEmpty()->intVal()->between(1,2),
        'name' =>                     v::notEmpty()->alpha()->length(1,55),
        'email' =>                    v::notEmpty()->email()->ConfirmEmail(),
        'user_type' =>                v::notEmpty()->intVal()->between(1,2),
        'CodePostal'   =>             v::notEmpty()->intVal(),
        'ville'   =>                  v::notEmpty()->alpha(),
        'password' =>                 v::noWhitespace()->notEmpty()->length(6),
        'password_confirmation' =>    v::noWhitespace()->notEmpty()->ConfirmPassword($request->getParam('password')),
        'phone' =>                    v::notEmpty()->phone(),
        'term' =>                     v::notEmpty()->equals(1),
    ]);


  // failed
    if($validation->failed()){
       $reponse = 'ko';
       //return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('create_account'));
    }



    if($validation){
        $user = User::create([
                                    'pseudo' =>   htmlentities($request->getParam('name')),
                                    'email' =>     htmlentities($request->getParam('email')),
                                    'telephone' => htmlentities($request->getParam('phone')),
                                    'password' =>  htmlentities(password_hash($request->getParam('password'),PASSWORD_DEFAULT)),
                                    'navigateur' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                                    'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],  
                                    'date_crea' => Carbon::now(),
                                    'civilite' => htmlentities($request->getParam('civilité')),  
                                    'user_type' => htmlentities($request->getParam('user_type')), 
                                    'code' => FunctionConfig::doGenerateCodeRandom(),
                                    'actif'=> 0,
                                    'codeuser' => FunctionConfig::doGenerateCodeUser()
                            ]);

        $reponse = 'ok';

     }

    echo json_encode(['reponse' => $reponse]);
```

When submitting my form fails, the php code is not interpreted. Why ???
this is the response in my DOM

[image]

Comment: how are you running this file? Is it a .js file included in an html/php file?

Comment: You're *breaking* PHP tags by escaping characters in them.  This:  `<\?php  if (errors) : \?>` won't trigger the PHP engine, *this* will: `<?php  if (errors) : ?>`  Though I suspect you're misunderstanding *when* the PHP code runs.  It won't be in response to the JavaScript, it'll be server-side before the page is even sent to the browser.

Comment: there's a lot that looks wrong here `alert('it's ok');` the last ``` does not have closing partner

Comment: you have (client-side) javascript, trying to parse (server-side) php code

Comment: you don't need this `$("#errors").html("<\?php  if (errors) : \?>"+`

Comment: See [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: PHP runs on the server and it has finished, packed up and gone home for the night before JavaScript even wakes up and starts tinkering on the client. So attempting to generate PHP *from* JavaScript is impossible (AJAX can call PHP though). `$("#errors").html("<?php  if (errors) :...` is never going to work; at best you'll get that `<?php ... ?>` tag in the HTML source code.